# how to bind java setup with my application setup?

Tags: inno-setup, install4j

i am beginner in java. i have done one application using java swing. Now i want make a setup or installer of that application.
i have been trying `install4j` for `.jar` to `.exe` file and `"inno setup compiler"` for setup and it run successfully. but problem is that this setup run on  machine where java is  not installed but  the application is not running and generate error for the java runtime environment is not installed.

how i can install java with my application on machine of the user of my system

Answer (score 3):

In `install4j` you need to configure your installer either as *static bundle* or as a *dynamic bundle*. A static bundle will ship the JRE with the installer and the dynamic will download the JRE at installation time.

From the [help page](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/media/steps/bundledJre.html):

> **Static bundle**
>
> The selected JRE will be distributed in your media file.
>
> **Dynamic bundle**
>
> A dynamic bundle is downloaded on demand. If the user already has a suitable JRE installed, that JRE will be used. If there is no such JRE available on the target machine, the installer will download the dynamically bundled JRE from the URL that you specify in the text fields below.